# Why does each React app require a seperate node_module file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I've noticed that even a simple webpage that shows "hello world" takes up over 600 MBs on my laptop, the `node_modules` folder alone is like 590MBs for me. Also, when I run `npx create-react-app` it takes couple minutes for everything to get ready and I'm assuming this is because for each React app npm generates a new `node_modules`?

Just out of curiosity, why is this the case? Why can't React apps just rely on a global dependency so there's only one `node_modules` for all apps (and if there is a way to do this, please let me know)?

Comment: Because different packages on your local machine may have different dependencies (or even different versions of the same dependency) and disk space is cheap. That's just how NPM works, if you want to optimise for other things look at e.g. https://pnpm.io/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the current architecture of an NPM project. Probably also a legacy.

> can't React apps just rely on a global dependency?

Well, actually they can. This is what PNPM is doing: https://pnpm.io/

Maybe a future version of NPM would also integrate that, but I do not expect it to come so quickly (when you have a whole ecosystem around your current architecture, the inertia to change is quite high).